# How to slove this issue - Task :react-native-push-notification:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED , import com.google.firebase.iid issue

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native

[image]![\node_modules\react-native-push-notification\android\src\main\java\com\dieam\reactnativepushnotification\modules\RNPushNotification.java:40: error: cannot find symbol

import com.google.firebase.iid.InstanceIdResult

Comment: Please refrain from using images, instead of code. Here is a [list of reasons why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3578036).

Answer (score 17):

There is some issue at 7.2.* version.
Try moving to the latest version or any 7.3.* version.

> npm i react-native-push-notification@latest

Comment: I did "npm i react-native-push-notification@3" and it worked. I think the issue might have been due to some update to the version 2 of this package.

Answer (score 11):

I faced this issue yesterday. And I fixed it by using the following steps.

First I uninstalled it.

```
npm uninstall react-native-push-notification
```

Then I installed it back in. (*Maybe you can just update it to the latest version as well. I just didn't know the npm command line for that*)

```
npm install react-native-push-notification
```

In `android/app/build.gradle`, add the following code in `defaultConfig` :

```
dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }
```

Also add:
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.1.0'

In `android/gradle.properties`, add the following code:

```
firebaseMessagingVersion=21.1.0
```

Delete `node_module`. (*Perhaps, you don't need to do this.*)

Finally, run `npm install`. You might have to run `yarn install` and `rebuild` your project again with `Android Studio` as well.

You probably don't need to follow every step in here. But these are what I did yesterday. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

Follow the steps.

1. `npm i react-native-push-notification@latest`
2. android/build.gradle

   ```
    buildscript {
   ext {
        //  ...
       firebaseMessagingVersion = '21.1.0'
   }
   ```

   }

These steps are worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me without adding `firebaseMessagingVersion` to android/build.gradle.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is posted to the official repository issue: https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/1979

if you are looking for the answer go to the comment:
https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/1979#issuecomment-839224339

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

try with updating the npm package.

- `"react-native-push-notification": "^7.3.0"`

by cleaning the cache also

- `cd android && ./gradlew clean`

Comment: this way not worked!

Answer (score 1):

I update these tow files:

#### `package.json` :

`"react-native-push-notification": "^7.2.2"` to `"react-native-push-notification": "^7.3.0"`

#### `android\app\build.gradle` :

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.3.0'` to `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:19.0.0'`

and its worked!